# A Generic method to remove items from a collection when the type is sure to have a particular property

Tags: c#

Consider this code.

`distinctBrandIds` is a collection of type `long`

```
List<long> distinctBrandIds = new List<long>{ 1, 5, 4};
```

`BrandYesNo` is a `Dictionary` with `BrandId` as key

```
Dictionary<long, bool> BrandYesNo = new Dictionary<long, bool>();
BrandYesNo.Add(1, false);
BrandYesNo.Add(2, false);
BrandYesNo.Add(3, false);
```

SomeClass has `BrandId` property

```
public class SomeClass{

    public int ItemId {get; set;}
    public long BrandId {get; set;}
    // other properties
}
```

Items from `CollectionOfSomeClass` are removed when `BrandId` equals `BrandId` key in `BrandYesNo` dictionary with the value of false

```
distinctBrandIds.ForEach((v) =>
{
    if (!(BrandYesNo[v]))
    {
        CollectionOfSomeClass.RemoveAll(sc => sc.BrandId == v);
    }
});
```

In other places, the same code repeats with other collections of types in place of `CollectionOfSomeClass`.
The common thing is that the type of which the other collection is made of also has `BrandId`. So the check is always on `BrandId` property.

To create a generic method there are suggestions to use reflection and on those lines I have this:

```
public void RemoveItemsFromList<T>(List<T> CollectionOfSomeClass, List<long> distinctBrandIds, object propertyToCheck) where T : class
{
    distinctBrandIds.ForEach((v) =>
    {
        if (!(BrandYesNo[v]))
        {
            CollectionOfSomeClass.RemoveAll((rd) => {
                PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty("BrandId");
                pi.GetValue(rd) == v;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The predicate is not correct.

How do I proceed with this?

Thanks in advance.

**Accepted Answer**
Initially that was not the case but I convinced the powers that be for CodeCaster's solution.

Comment: You could also use `dynamic` but you'd have the same issue as your solution: an impact on performance. Is it possible to make the classes implement a common interface with a `BrandId` property?

Comment: Although introducing an interface is a good idea I am dealing with legacy code and changes will be in too many places.

Comment: Note that your code will also fail if since `GetValue` returns an object. Since `==` is bound at compile time, object comparison will be used as opposed to value which is not what you want. You could make it work by casting `GetValue` to a long, which will work if `BrandId` is a long in all the classes.

Comment: "changes in to many places" is not a good excuse to sacrifice type safety IMHO. Using reflection inappropriately risks making your code difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for reflection here, if you know and control the types that are to be processed by this method. Given you say

> The common thing is that the type of which the other collection is made of also has `BrandId`. So the check is always on `BrandId` property.

Create an interface:

```
public interface IBrand
{
    long BrandId { get; }
}
```

Apply that to the appropriate classes:

```
public class SomeClass : IBrand 
{ ... }
```

And modify your constraint:

```
public void RemoveItemsFromList<T>(List<T> CollectionOfSomeClass, List<long> distinctBrandIds)
    where T : IBrand
{
    distinctBrandIds.ForEach((v) =>
    {
        if (!(BrandYesNo[v]))
        {
            CollectionOfSomeClass.RemoveAll(rd => rd.BrandId == v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to a comment by OP he's working with legacy code, so this might not be possible. But if possible this is the best answer

Comment: Adding an interface to a handful of classes seems less invasive to me than using reflection risking that something breaks later on, but that's like my opinion.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'd say it's more invasive but safer. My answer below was posted after the OP confirmed modifying the classes was not an option for him/her. If it wasn't the case, your solution would definitely be way to go.

Comment: @vc74 yeah "less invasive" doesn't really carry across what I meant, which is that adding an interface won't break anything else while giving you compile-time safety, as opposed to using reflection. We shouldn't be afraid to modify existing classes. How many can it be, 5, 10, 25? The OP is going to go through their code and add this method call in certain places, very little effort required to F12 (Go To Definition) of the classes where they are being used, and implementing the interface.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate my comment, the following code should work but will be slow:

```
public void RemoveItemsFromList<T>(List<T> CollectionOfSomeClass, 
    List<long> distinctBrandIds) 
    where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty("BrandId");
            
    distinctBrandIds.ForEach(v =>
    {
        if (!(BrandYesNo[v]))
        {
            CollectionOfSomeClass.RemoveAll(rd => ((long)pi.GetValue(rd) == v));
        }
    });
}
```

Or use `Equals`.

Note that this code should only be used if you don't have access to the classes code or cannot modify it. If not the case, @CodeMaster's solution is much safer + faster.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to [@vc 74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446279/vc-74)s answer, you could use reflection but cache it using a dictionary:

```cs
// Stores functions that take objects with "BrandId" properties
// and returns the value of the "BrandId" property casted to long
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object, long>> _getBrandId = new();

public void RemoveItemsFromList<T>(List<T> CollectionOfSomeClass, 
    List<long> distinctBrandIds) 
    where T : class
{
    // Check if the function is already cached
    if (!_getBrandId.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var getBrandId))
    {
        // Create the lambda using an expression tree
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, long>>(
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.Property(
                    Expression.Parameter(typeof(object)),
                    "BrandId"),
                typeof(long)),
            target);

        // Store it to the cache
        getBrandId = _getBrandId[typeof(T)] = lambda.Compile();
    }

    distinctBrandIds.ForEach((v) =>
    {
        if (BrandYesNo[v]) continue;

        CollectionOfSomeClass.RemoveAll(rd => getBrandId(rd) == v);
    });
}
```